# Run and deploy Cordova app on Windows Device

Tags: cordova, win-universal-app, visual-studio-cordova

I've made myself a Cordova app outside Visual Studio. I've been using Sublime to test and work on it. Now I want to add it to the Windows App Store, but I want to test it first.

So I've made a Visual Studio Cordova project and added all my files to the project.
After a while I've managed to get rid of all the errors and exceptions.

- In my config.xml file I've chosen `Windows 10.0` as a `Windows Target Version`.
- I've chosen `Windows-x64` as a processor and ran the application.
- The only thing I've got to see was this:
  [image]

Does anybody have an idea how I can test my working application (tested it through `ripple emulate` within Sublime Editor) inside Visual Studio?

I'll provide code if needed.

Comment: Do you see any errors coming out of the JS console in VS? You can also go to the [project name]/platforms/windows folder and open your UWP project inside VS and look at errors there.

Comment: It looks like your home page may be incorrect - is config.xml pointing at the right HTML file for your home page?

Comment: @JordanMatthiesen yea, it's pointing to the correct html.

Comment: If you want to upload your source somewhere, or email it to me (jordan.matthiesen -at- microsoft.com) I can take a look and post back a suggestion here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Check your email :)